# Python: Xlib -- How can I raise(bring to top) windows?

Tags: python, linux, xlib

I've tried using:

```
   win.configure(stack_mode=X.TopIf)
   win.set_input_focus(X.RevertToParent, X.CurrentTime)
```

However even without any focus loss prevention on my window manager this does not work, does anyone know of another way to do this? Xlib or not.

Answer (score 3):

There is a command-line tool called [wmctrl](http://tripie.sweb.cz/utils/wmctrl/) which allows you to interact with EWMH/NetWM-compatible X window managers.

For example,

```
wmctrl -l
```

lists all the windows managed by the window manager, and

```
wmctrl -a Mozilla
```

makes active the first window in the list which has the string "Mozilla" in its title.
There are other ways to select windows; the above is just an example.

wmctrl enables you to move and resize windows too.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
window=Display().screen().root.query_pointer().child
window.set_input_focus(X.RevertToParent, X.CurrentTime)
window.configure(stack_mode=X.Above)
```

Comment: adding a `display.sync()` helps force it, I needed this line for Xorg on Ubuntu

Comment: What is X? -----

Comment: @Raphael
add "from Xlib import X" in the head of your python code,   you need "sudo apt install python3-xlib" first

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is the solution:
[[Xlib] Force Raise/Map/Focus a given Window](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2008-August/037684.html)

A solution given (follow the thread) involves using wnck, which in Python is a part of the Gtk+ bindings.