# Linux: xterm - starting window as always on top

Tags: python, linux, console, xterm

I am intresting in launching an xterm window from python code in following way:

```
cmd = './my_task'
subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-t', 'my_task', '-e', cmd])
```

However, I want this xterm session to be set to **always on top** from command line.

One way I was able to do this is by doing this:

```
cmd = 'wmcntl -r 'my_task' -b add,above; ./my_task'
subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-t', 'my_task', '-e', cmd])
```

But this requires the machine to have **wmctrl** installed.

Is there a **standard way** of doing this (I don't need a cross platform solution, just for Linux)

Thanks,

Itay

Comment: @shellter - you might be right, but I am thinking the solution might be using the x window protocol if not by passing a secert parameter to xterm

Comment: Sorry, this first struck me as a user level Q. I see there really is coding involved ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: Use Python/Xlib: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3297152/1554386 ?

Comment: The suggested answers in the link provided by [@alastair-mccormack](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1554386/alastair-mccormack) would work; if there were an accepted answer, it would make this a duplicate.